# Tool For Generating Formula for Projection

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, proj, datum

I am using Proj4Js for northing,easting to lat,long transformation.

My Datum is "AGD84" and projection is "Transverse Mercator".

While doing so I found that if I don't specify "+proj" parameter in the definition file of source coordinate system then it gives me error saying "Projection Code Not Found".

I found that "Proj4Js" is having some ready made library of projection code but nothing out of them is useful to me.

Can anyone suggest any tool in which if we pass datum & projection name then automatically it generates projection specific formula which can be usable with Proj4Js ?

Comment: have you checked spatialreference.org? a search for AGD84 gives: http://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=AGD84

Answer (score 1):

you can use http://spatialreference.org which has previously added Proj4js format file..
The only thing you will do is that search and then get Proj4js file as following example...

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4203"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=aust_SA +no_defs";
```

beside this if you add some Proj4js defiantion to in your js file you can reach them on openlayers as weiting this:

to add the script file any proj defination:

> Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27563"]="+title=LAMB sud france  +proj=lcc
>   +lat_1=44.1 +lat_0=44.1 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.999877499 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m";

to get proj defination:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27563"]
```

it will return you as a result of defination which you want...

i hope it helps you...

Comment: thanks Aragon...it really helped me....by the way do you know any tool in which if we input N,E then Lat,Long is returned by the tool?